# iOS - Can I use the Status Bar from Callkit for other feature?

Tags: ios, callkit

Can I use the Status Bar (Green/ Blue/ Red) from Callkit for other feature that is not Call? And if we dont use all the api from the Callkit, will Apple approve the app?

Comment: The double height status bar is shown by iOS when you are on a call, an app is recording in the background or using location. You cannot display this bar yourself in other conditions and you cannot customise the message.

Comment: ah thank you Paulw!

Answer (score 0):

Voice Memos is red, which is the color typically used for 'Recording'.
Calls are green, which is the color of the Phone app's icon and is used in several places in the app (e.g., the Accept button).
AirPlay is blue, which is the color that Apple typically associates with both wireless and music (AirPort and Bluetooth logos are blue, iTunes' icon is blue, the Remote app's icon is blue).
Personal hotspot is blue, which again is the color of 'wireless。 you cannot customise the message.